# Removing checking for .IsWhiteSpace

Tags: c#

I want to remove the check for `.IsWhiteSpace`. Basically the code search for a word on a RichTextBox. If the word matches it will execute a code. Prior to checking if the word exist it will make check if all the words from the RichTextBox are `.IsWhiteSpace`. I wanted to remove this if check. Here is the code:

```
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) | JSSyntaxProvider.GetSpecials.Contains(text[i]))
```

The section I want to change is the `if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]))` from the the code. Basically it is checking if all the words on the text are .IsWhiteSpace. How can I make the check without them being .IsWhiteSpace?

Comment: string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the method, it's impossible for us to suggest a way to refactor your code so you maintain your functionality while removing the offending code.

Comment: A "word" usually means a sequence of letters. Letters are different from whitespace, so I don't understand what it means to check if words are whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the comments without knowing what happens after the iswhitespace check its hard to give you a good solution that best fits your problem.

One solution would be to

```
void CheckWordsInRun(Run run)
{
    string text = run.Text;
    int sIndex = 0;
    int eIndex = 0;
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    foreach(string word in words)
    {
        //Do some logic
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not from using the string itself.  If the string is contained within a RichTextboxField you could use something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Once you have a starting point you iterate forwards and backwards until you find " ".  Once you have the start and end indexes of the word you can use the substring command to get the clicked word.